# Add Google Ads Conversion Snippet to Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, google-tag-manager, prestashop-1.6, google-ads-api

I'm following the instructions to get this working with the official Google Docs and I got a problem when inserting the snippet in the order confirmation template:

1. First, it said that I must insert it in the header, which in this template is impossible so i'm adding it at the bottom of the body or am I wrong about this?
2. The snippet itself:

   ```
   <!-- Event snippet for Compra Realizada conversion page -->
   <script> 
   {literal}
   gtag('event', 'conversion', { 'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX/hFH0CLjs_mwQhvnEowM', 'transaction_id': '{$id_order_formatted}' });
   {/literal}
   </script>
   ```

It seems that is not doing the conversion right? Is the code above correct?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are Spanish, I assume that you must understand me better in Spanish:
You are adding the header of AG but you are not defining the event

Head

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX-X"></script>
```

Gtag load Just after declaring the AG label of the head:

```
 <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
             gtag('js', new Date());

             gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
 </script>
```

Then call the event that is going to run in its corresponding function click, load, mouslistener, etc:

```
<script>    
      gtag('event','formSend'});
</script>
```

Example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX-X"></script>
    <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                 gtag('js', new Date());

                 gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="foo" href="javascript:void(0)">Send Info</a>
    <script>
        function sendGat() {
            gtag('event','formSend');
            console.log("Gat Send");
        }
        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var bar = document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", sendGat);
        }, false );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to use English in this site. There's another SO for Spanish https://es.stackoverflow.com/ :)